# new Typescript project - IntelliJ seems to pick up config, but Gulp doesn't

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, typescript, gulp, typescript-typings

I have a new Typescript project and I'm using Gulp to build, clean, deploy etc.

At the moment its a fairly empty project and I've used npm to install the modules and Typings.  The jQuery typing has been included and when inside intelliJ (v15) if I have the following -

```
class Person {

constructor(name: string ) {
    this.name = name;
}
name: string;
}

function greeter (person: Person ) {
    return "hallo " + person.name;
}

var person = new Person("bert");

$(document).ready(function(){
    var message = greeter( person );
    $("#status")[0].innerHTML = message;
});
```

Then inside intellij it all appears to be fine - as it in gives no errors and if I hover of the $ then it shows the tooltip of index.d.ts so it is picking up the typing.

But when I use Gulp the build fails **- error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.**

For the Gulp task I'm using the below -

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', { target : "ES2015" });
var tsResult = gulp.src('./src/ts/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));

return merge([ // Merge the two output streams, so this task is finished when the IO of both operations are done.
    tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('release/definitions')),
    tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('release/js'))
]);
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

package.json -

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-diff": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-header": "^1.8.8",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "gulp-tslint": "^6.1.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "merge2": "^1.0.2",    
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json (not using tsd.json as doc suggest its not needed now)

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "watch":true,
        "moduleResolution" : "node",
        "outDir":"./dist/"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "dist",
      "release"
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I place this at top of the TS file then Gulp will build as expected - but this seems to go against everything I've read.  So is there a way to get Gulp to pick up this file without having to reference it in each TS file.

/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />

Comment: How you installed JQuery typing ??

Comment: I installed jQuery using both NPM for the node module and using Typings for the d.ts file.

typings install dt~jquery --global --save-dev

So I can see it in the typings.json file - 
"globalDevDependencies": {
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160704162008"
  }

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, it does seem as if Gulp isn't picking up the index.d.ts file under typings.  Not sure how to force it to do so.

Comment: could you please show your package.json and tsd.json??

Comment: added them to the Q. I don't use the tsd.json as various documentation suggested that the tsconfig.json has replaced it